# VBA loop with arrays duplicating output

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I'm new to using arrays (and VBA in general) and I'm trying to incorporate a series of arrays into a module that formats SPSS syntax output in worksheets in a single workbook. Below is my code, which works, but is duplicating the results that are found. I think it has something to do with the order of my loops but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub FindValues()

Call CreateSummary

'This code will build the initial summary file

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    MsgBox ("It will take a moment for data to appear, please be patient if data does not immediately appear")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim i2 As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim CopiedRows As Integer
    Dim LocationA(4) As String
    Dim LocationB(4) As String
    Dim LocationC(4) As String
    Dim LocationD(4) As String
    Dim VariableA(4) As Integer
    Dim VariableB(4) As Integer
    Dim ColumnA(4) As String
    Dim ColumnB(4) As String
    Dim n As Long

    'Find DateTime Info
    LocationA(1) = "Date_Time"
    LocationB(1) = "Quarter"
    LocationC(1) = "N"
    LocationD(1) = "Minimum"
    VariableA(1) = 1
    VariableB(1) = 1
    ColumnA(1) = "B"
    ColumnB(1) = "C"

    LocationA(2) = "Dur*"
    LocationB(2) = "Methodology_ID"
    LocationC(2) = "Mean"
    LocationD(2) = "N"
    VariableA(2) = 1
    VariableB(2) = 1
    ColumnA(2) = "C"
    ColumnB(2) = "D"

    LocationA(3) = "WebTimeout"
    LocationB(3) = "Methodology_ID"
    LocationC(3) = "Mean"
    LocationD(3) = "N"
    VariableA(3) = 1
    VariableB(3) = 1
    ColumnA(3) = "C"
    ColumnB(3) = "D"

    'LocationA(4) = "Crosstabulation"
    'LocationB(4) = "Quarter"
    'LocationC(4) = "N"
    'LocationD(4) = "Minimum"
    'VariableA(4) = 1

    'Find OSAT Data
    'LocationA(2) = "*Report*"
    'LocationB(2) = "*CallMonth*"
    'LocationC(2) = "Mean*"
    'LocationD(2) = "*Overall*"
    'VariableA(2) = 2

    For Each ws In Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Starting row
    i = 1
    'Find LastRow
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    If ws.Name <> "Run Macros" Then

        Do While i <= LastRow
            For x = 1 To 3

            If ws.Range("A" & i).Value Like LocationA(x) And ws.Range("A" & i + 1).Value Like LocationB(x) And ws.Range(ColumnA(x) & i + VariableA(x)).Value Like LocationC(x) And ws.Range(ColumnB(x) & i + VariableB(x)).Value Like LocationD(x) Then
            CopiedRows = 0
            i2 = i

                Do While ws.Range("A" & i2 + 1).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = 1 And ws.Range("A" & i2 + 1).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = 4
                i2 = i2 + 1
                CopiedRows = CopiedRows + 1
                Loop
                n = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 4
                ws.Rows(i & ":" & i + CopiedRows).Copy Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & n)
            On Error Resume Next
            End If
            Next x
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End If
    Next

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The VBA code aside, could you share what some description of what you are trying to do with the SPSS output? Merge multiple excel output from SPSS into a single file? What's the purpose of the code you post and beyond that what is the over aim? As your approach could well be done somewhat easier some other-how...

Comment: Of course...
I get a series of spreadsheets that contain SPSS output that is not organized, each sheet has multiple data tables with minimal headings to distinguish between them. I'm trying to take these three sheets and combine them into a single sheet that is organized from top to bottom on the data that I need - the order that I need the data in is consistent each time the SPSS is run. My overall aim is to simplify the process of digging through 3 worksheets with 80 data tables to try to find what I want.

Comment: You may want to consider using the TITLE command in SPSS before any procedure that generates any output as a way of identifying (the start of) that particular output. If it is CTABLES output then it has an internal TITLE sub-command which would work equivalently also. This doesn't answer your question at hand, I understand, but may give you ideas how to setup your process perhaps a little better to then not have to use additional complicated code? I don't know....

Answer (score 0):

This works if anyone want to reuse this code...

```
  For x = 1 To 3 Step 1
            For Each ws In Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                'Starting row
                i = 1
                'Find LastRow
                LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                Do While i <= LastRow
                    If ws.Name <> "Run Macros" Or ws.Name <> "Summary" Then
                    If ws.Range("A" & i).Value Like LocationA(x) And ws.Range("A" & i + 1).Value Like LocationB(x) And ws.Range(ColumnA(x) & i + VariableA(x)).Value Like LocationC(x) And ws.Range(ColumnB(x) & i + VariableB(x)).Value Like LocationD(x) Then
                        CopiedRows = 0
                        i2 = i
                        Do While ws.Range("A" & i2 + 1).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = 1 And ws.Range("A" & i2 + 1).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = 4
                        i2 = i2 + 1
                    CopiedRows = CopiedRows + 1
                    Loop
                        n = Sheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 4
                        ws.Rows(i & ":" & i + CopiedRows).Copy Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & n)
                        Exit For
                        On Error Resume Next
                    End If
                    End If
                i = i + 1
                Loop
            Next
        Next x
```